# Cannot read property of data null in ReactJs when fetching from JSON

Tags: reactjs, fetch

I am new to react andtrying to fetch JSON data in React JS but getting this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of null
```

My code is :

```
import React from 'react';

export default class FetchJson extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount()
    {
        fetch('https://api.myjson.com/bins/9i63i')
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((findresponse) =>{
            this.setState({ data: findresponse })
            //console.log(this.state.data);
            //console.log(findresponse.DesignName);

        })
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <ul>
                {this.state.data.map((x,i) => <li key={i}>{x.DesignName}</li>)}
            </ul>
        );
    }
}
```

You can see the json data here: `http://myjson.com/9i63i`
I want to retrieve value for key `DesignName` which is `part1` which is not happening.
See the commented lines: both gives me the value. But when i try to access it inside return method inside render. I get error : `TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of null` in this line:

```
{this.state.data.map((x,i) => <li key={i}>{x.DesignName}</li>)}
```

How to solve this?

Comment: Probably because `render()` runs before you're `.then()` the callback has set the state (as this happens asynchronously). Check that `this.state` is defined before you try and map it: `{this.state && this.state.data.map((x,i)...}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DesignName is not an array in the response.

You can define your state like this:

```
 state = {
    data: null
  }
```

And display the DesignName using [inline if with logical && operator](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator) to solve null problem.

```
  render() {   
    return (
      <div>
        DesignName: { this.state.data && this.state.data.DesignName}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-matsumoto-87w3z)

Comment: thanks, conditional rendering solved my problem and the data was retrieved by `this.state.data.DesignName`.

Comment: done. Also i need access nested data, if you see the json then inside `ComponentInfo` there are `ComponentName, FkComponentCategory, PartNumber, Manufacturer, Power, ComponentLevelPassPercentage`. How can I access those? I tried `this.state.data.ComponentInfo.ComponentName` But didn't worked

Comment: @AnishArya  ComponentInfo is an array. You can access it by index `this.state.data.ComponentInfo[0].ComponentName`  or if you want to display them you can use map.

Comment: that worked, how to access whole array and display?

Comment: @AnishArya try to use map, I will  update codesandbox later.

Comment: @AnishArya you can display component names like [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-matsumoto-87w3z). Please note that some component's null, so I filtered before map.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206061/discussion-between-anish-arya-and-suleymansah).

Answer (score 2):

You can use an `isLoading` flag while waiting for your api call to finish.

```
state = {
   data: null,
   isLoading:true
}

render() { 
  if(this.state.isLoading) { 
    return(<div>loading</div>); 
  }
  return(
   <ul>
    {this.state.data.map((x,i) => <li key={i}>{x.DesignName}</li>)}
   </ul>
  );
```

when your api call has finished, you can update the state like this:

```
this.setState({ data: findresponse, isLoading:false })
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, I endorse this answer as a clean solution to the issue.